# optimal solution for following scenario using java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

integer array has given. Even numbers should in even indexes and odd numbers should in odd indexes.  you have to check whether given array is satisfied that condition.

my implementation is here....

```
public void isSatisfied(int [] arr){

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){  

        int r_val=arr[i]%2;
        int r_index=i%2;

        if((r_val==1)&&(r_index==1)){

            if(i==arr.length-1){
                System.out.println("yes");
            }
            continue;
        }
        else if((r_val==0)&&(r_index==0)){
            if(i==arr.length-1){
                System.out.println("yes");
            }
            continue;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("no");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

what will be the best implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The sum of a particular index and the value at that index* must be **even**, otherwise the array doesn't satisfy your condition:

```
public boolean isSatisfied(int[] arr) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
        if ((i + arr[i]) % 2 != 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: just to nitpick: this is dangerous if you approach Integer.MAX_VALUE :P

Answer (score 1):

```
public void isSatisfied(int [] arr){

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){  

        int r_val=arr[i]%2;
        int r_index=i%2;

        if(r_val!=r_index){
            System.out.println("no");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("yes");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Best" is often a quetion of opinion. Your code is good enough, here are a few tips:

1) Don't mix logic with presentation. In your loop, save the state (array is correct or not) to a boolean variable. After the loop, print whatever you want based in the variable (and so you won't have several "yes" repeated (and followed maybe by a "no"), which I would find confusing.

2) If you use the `if-else-if` construct, the `continue`s are not needed. Use one form of the other to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

It makes more sense to have a method named `isX` return `boolean`.

```
public boolean isSatisfied(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0 && arr[i] % 2 != 0)
            return false;
        if (i % 2 == 1 && arr[i] % 2 == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a little modified version of your code. 
package com.mtk;

public class ArrayTest {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {2,3,4,5,6};        
        isSatisfied(arr);
    }

    private static void isSatisfied(int[] arr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if( i%2 == 0 && arr[i]%2 == 0) ; // do nothing
            else if (i%2 == 1 && arr[i]%2 == 1) ; // do nothing
            else {
                System.out.println("No");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }
}
```